# Is it possible to generate Django Model from UML

Tags: django-models, uml

is there any way to create Django Models from a given UML drawing (e.g. in diagrams.net).
Since I am still new to Django I would like to learn best practices on how to generate models in the most efficient ways.
Thanks inadvance!

Comment: From a drawing you can take a picture. Or maybe you have some AI that can do more. But to generate anything you need the model that was used to create the UML diagram. If it was some Paint or Visio go to the beginning of my comment.

Comment: I just looked at diagrams.net. In a nutshell my top comment applies. This is another Visio.

Comment: Yes, it's a better visio. I meant diagrams.net just as an example could also be visio or another drwaing tool that provides the model

Comment: See what I said about drawing tools: not possible.